# Python 3: taking a json and splitting it into smaller jsons

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, split

So I have a file with a json that looks like:

```
{
      "a":{
             "ab":2,
             "cd":3
      },
      "b":{
             "ef":2,
             "gh":3
      },
      "c":{
             "ij":2,
             "kl":3
      }

}
```

So in python, I would like to import this json from the file, and then from that break it into separate jsons, each in a separate variable, such that each variable would look like:

```
json1 = {
             "a":{
                    "ab":2,
                    "cd":3
             }
        }
##etc.
```

And these json variables should function as variables that can be converted to json objects, via methods like `json.load`, or `json.dump`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you had those variables you want, I would have recommended storing them in something like a dictionary, like you have currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've imported the file with `json.load`, what you have is just a plain old Python dict:

```
with open('bigfile.json') as f:
    bigd = json.load('bigfile.json')
```

And if you iterate over `items()` for a dict, what you get is key-value pairs.

```
for key, value in bigd.items():
```

And turning a key-value pair back into a single-item dict is trivial.

```
    smalld = {key: value}
```

At which point you have a dict again, so you can `json.dump` it.

```
    with open(f'smallfile-{key}.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(f, smalld)
```

Or whatever else you want to do with them. For example, `append` each `smalld` to a `listodicts`, or convert its `repr` to ASCII art and send it to `/dev/lpr0`, or whatever.